# Why did I get capped at 186 reputation points today?

Tags: support, reputation

Up until now the rep cap allowed up to 200 points in upvotes.  If you selected an answer or if your answer was selected, that didn't count toward the cap.  But today I noticed I have 201 points, including 15 points for an answer being selected, and only 6 points on an answer upvote and another upvote with no points.

Has the reputation cap been redefined or changed?

Comment: I hit 215 the other day... by any chance did you downvote anything today? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32571/166646

Comment: No downvoting today.  I usually leave a browser window open with tabs for questions/answers I want to up/downvote and go through them at once.  It's part of me looking at older questions as well as new ones to see what's been done on the site.

Comment: Let's test this out. Let's see what happens when 30 people upvote one of my answers in a single day, and see if the reputation cap holds:-) Or it could be shared among multiple answers, I'm not picky;-)

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: I'm deeply touched that you're willing to be the subject of an experiment for my sake, but it's not the upvotes that are the issue as much as the answer selection points.

Comment: @Tango - volunteering to be experimented on is an old and honorable tradition on SE sites - [1](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3162/1044)

Answer (score 3):

I think what happened is that you deleted one or more posts of yours today, totaling 30 reputation points from upvotes (e.g. a +3 answer, a +6 question, or a mix of these) and -6 reputation points from downvotes (i.e. 3 downvotes). The deleted upvotes still count against the cap, because the deletion is not reflected in the counter that's used for the cap. The deletion of the downvotes, on the other hand, seems to have been reflected in the cap, so that you could get 6 points back, for a total of 186 (excluding acceptance rep which is not taken into account for the daily rep cap).

You should be able to make things right by recalculating your reputation from the real data. Your reputation total is normally not calculated from the real data, it's a running total that events like getting votes update. Some rare events such as deletions don't update that running total. Visit [`/reputation`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) to see a full audit of your real reputation. There's a button to `Trigger Reputation Recalc`. If you press this button, your on-site rep will be the `total rep` figure at the bottom of the `/reputation` page.

Note that a rep recalc may well decrease your rep, if you had a rep surplus (e.g. from now-deleted posts) that hadn't been properly taken into account. You can't do a recalc just for today, it's all or nothing.

Comment: I thought about recalculating.  I'll get my 14 points back -- but I'll lose some more.  At least there's not a huge gap to lose if I recalc.  I'm going to keep tabs on the difference between the /reputation page and my page and probably do a recalc at some time so if there is a recalc in the future, I don't lose hundreds of points at a time.

Comment: Is the rep recalc going to affect the count of days of 200+ rep for his Epic badge?

Comment: @DVK I don't think so, the Epic/Legendary badges seem to have their own count. I know I got the Legendary badge a few days too soon on [unix.se].

Answer (score 1):

The reputation cap has not changed. Specifically, this comes from the FAQ:

You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

So, accepted answers and bounties are not subject to the reputation cap.

Comment: Kevin gave me a link to the audit page -- that shows a different total (which seems correct).  On my user page, it was reading that I had 201 points, **including** 15 points for an accepted answer, instead of 215 points.