# Why is my daily rep at 199 when I have "dead rep"?

Tags: support, reputation

So I had a couple good answers yesterday and were fortunate enough to receive a large number of up-votes. I continued along with daily activities that did include some down votes on answers. My total activity ended looking like this:

[image: daily activity screen cap]

As you can see I totaled 199 reputation... why is this not 200? Should the "dead rep" from up-votes that would have pushed me over the cap kicked in?

[image: expanded activity screen cap]

I have up-votes that have recorded no rep. A secondary question, with the day showing 199 does this also mean that I did not get credit toward a Legendary badge as I did not "earn 200 daily reputation"?

For what it's worth, I went through my profile and manually counted the days I had 200+ rep recorded and came up with 52. My progress toward the Legendary badge is currently at 64, so there twelve days where I am showing less than 200 reputation but still counted toward badge progress. My hunch is that those days are similar to this example (there were a few other 198-199 days).

Comment: Related: [Why did I get capped at 186 reputation points today?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1470/31394) (although some of the information there is out of date).

Answer (score 2):

For obvious reasons when I go to your profile I cannot see your downvotes, however, tracking the +2 and +1 rep gains I think the following has happened as shown on your profile. Also worth noting that I see a rep total of 205 which corresponds to what your profile says (199 + 6 hidden DVs).

- 19:21 - You hit the rep cap
- 19:32 - You recieve +2 to reimburse you for the downvotes at 15:02 and 15:03
- 20:10 - You receive +2 to reimburse you for the downvotes at 20:01 and 20:08
- 20:49 - You receive +1 to reimburse you for the downvote at 20:27

It would appear as if the downvote at 20:09 never shows to be reimbursed on your profile. This could be because it was "too close" to the upvote at 20:10 that, that one doesn't see the downvote. The upvote at 20:14 then thinks the upvote at 20:10 reimbursed the +1 and so doesn't reimburse you.

I would imagine that this is actually just a visual thing though and behind the scenes you actually did hit 200 rep. To check it might be worth looking in the Achievements dropdown menu and seeing what that says.

On the note about the Legendary badge, it is in my experience that the badge increases when you hit 200. As you hit 200 at 19:32 before the further downvotes and the +2 was reimbursed from the first two the badge should have increased its count. As Rand has said in a comment though apparently the count will decrease if you subsequently fall back under 200 rep throughout the day. I have not noticed this myself though so will take his word for it.

Comment: No, the Legendary badge checks the end-of-day total. If you hit 200 and get downvoted just before midnight, that day doesn't count. (Source: it happened to me a few years ago.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor My experience tells me different as I've seen the count increase mid day but I don't know the official answer sure.

Comment: Yes, it increases mid-day, but then decreases again if you drop below 200 later.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Oh fair enough, not sure if I've had that happen to me but I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I made an edit to the question... according to my profile I only have 52 das of 200+ rep but my badge progress is 64. Either I can't count (which knowing me is possible) or Carrot might be onto something.